# Is there any public and reasonably accurate 3D scan from a Cray-2 computer?

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design, scanning

I'm thinking about building a Cray-2 inspired cluster. I'm concerned about the exterior housing modules, proportions and panels.

Has anyone done a good 3D scan of one?

Comment: I believe that, with the last changes, the question has more objective answers and, while not one of the topics described in https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, it doesn't fall into the "bad question" criteria either.

Comment: you did nothing to change the scope or target of the question rbanffy: Your question is "Where to find a model of X", which is *not* Troubleshooting, Repair, Best Practice, Technology, Material, Capabilities, how to design your OWN parts or something about print services. It stays off topic.

Comment: "The following topics are merely suggestions, topics are not necessarily limited to the following and all topics are subject to community discretion" (from https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

LMGTFY, etc. etc.   Depends on the amount of detail you want.  A cheap starter: [here](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:26671), or [here](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1246709) or [irrational fruit](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2610764)

Comment: None of these is a Cray 2. LMGTFY, this is what a Cray 2 looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cray-2#/media/File:CRAY-2_IMG_8915-8913-8912a.jpg